How to get error bars for odds ratio from logistic regression output from R
data(mtcars)

# Fit logistic regression model
model <- glm(am ~ mpg, data = mtcars, family = binomial)

# Summarize the model
summary(model)

gives:
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)  -6.6035     2.3514  -2.808  0.00498 **
mpg           0.3070     0.1148   2.673  0.00751 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 43.230  on 31  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 29.675  on 30  degrees of freedom
AIC: 33.675

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

I think I know to get the odds ratio of the estimate, I go exp(0.3070), which is 1.3593411, but if I wanted to plot that and give error bars to communicate uncertainty how would I do that? I do not think that I can directly take the standard error from the model summary since I have now transformed the estimate. What to do?

You can use something like $\exp(0.3070-2\times 0.1148)$ and  $\exp(0.3070+2\times 0.1148)$ for the confidence interval on the odds or whatever value of $2$ you prefer.  It is asymmetric, but that is the nature of the transformation.

You can use the delta method to approximate an estimate of the standard error of the odds ratio estimate; but, owing to the asymmetry of the OR estimate's distribution mentioned by @Henry, that's rarely, if ever, used to construct error bars.
